# SSL with WebSphere MQ 7

Tags: java, spring, ssl, ibm-mq

Basically I have two problems:

### Optional SSL for Queue Manager not working as expected

I have QM configured well. For testing I'm using MQIVP Java class from WebSphere MQ installation. Without SSL configured I have no problem to run MQIVP successfully. When I set up QM SSL authentication as optional it stops working, probably not so optional, any idea?

Another additional property is that when using Spring and SSL authentication as required I have no problem to connect to QM without additional configuration for Spring (comparing with the one without SSL)

### Java SSL Logging not working as expected

According to that [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0510_fehners/0510_fehners.html) I configured trustStore and keyStore, but when trying to use SSL with MQIVP no additional logging is in the log.

I have properties set:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\trustStore.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trust
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\keyStore.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=key
```

Answer (score 1):

I know for the keyStore you just specify the file name without the extention, so try this:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\keyStore"
```

You may also try the same for the trustStore.

Comment: Thanks for a hint, I saw this info before, but my expectation was that there will be an error if this is incorrect. I tried this, no progress (no logging and not working).

Comment: I found that it is with `.jks` suffix also.

Comment: Hi there @Betlista. Sorry I didn't have a chance to respond to your logging issue earlier. I haven't done this before in JMS, however there is a article found on debugging that might help. Check this out: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)